# Simulating an object under constant acceleration with a maximum speed

Tags: game-physics, computational-geometry

I am trying to simulate an object in 2 dimensions with a set maximum speed, and I'm having difficulty constructing a mathematical model of the objects behaviour when it is at maximum speed but it is both not moving in the correct direction *and* further acceleration is partially blocked by the maximum speed limit.

E.g. it's maximum speed is √2, it's currently heading at (1,1) and it should really be heading at (√2, 0). If it just accelerates directly along the x-axis, it would break the speed limit it is working under.

Instead it needs to 'slide' it's velocity round to the correct direction over the course of time. What I have been doing is doing is calculating the new speed and scaling it by the maximum if it gets too high:

```
newVelocity = oldVelocity + acceleration * dt;
if(newVelocity.getLength() > maxSpeed){
    newVelocity = newVelocity.scale(maxSpeed);
}
```

Which does work (sort of), but I'm needing to refactor it to be smoother - as in, not dependent on the granularity of the simulation - at the moment, I get different results if I do one pass as opposed to (say) two passes with half the value of dt.

What I have been trying to do is model it as the speed being a point on the circle, and then calculating the amount of the acceleration applied as the tangent of the circle

[Diagram of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP73w.png)

But (and this is where my mechanics and calculus fails me) is how to turn this calculation of the momentary angular velocity derived from the current velocity angle and the acceleration applied into a time based formula which I can use to work out the change in actual velocity over a single simulation tick.

I'm almost certain that this problem has a fairly straightforward solution - I'm just unable to work out what set of terms to google for.

Comment: Why not just clamp the speed whenever it exceeds the limit, by rescaling the velocity vector?

Answer (score 0):

If you're currently at v=(1,1) and you want to accelerate to v=(√2, 0), you have two options.

1. Follow the straight line from v=(1,1) to v=(√2,0), by applying a constant acceleration proportional to (√2-1,1) for a period of time. During this time, the object will be traveling slower than its maximum speed, but it will get to its desired velocity as quickly as possible.
2. Follow the curve of maximum velocity by, in each instant, applying the maximum acceleration with a direction *perpendicular to the current velocity*. In this instance you're trying to turn right, so when your velocity is (1,1) your acceleration will be proportional to (1,-1), and just before your velocity is (√2,0) your velocity will be almost proportional to (0,-√2). It sounds like this is the one you want to do, but keep in mind that it's not necessarily optimal.

Now some quick calculations. Your velocity circle has radius `maxSpeed`, meaning that it has circumference `2*π*maxSpeed`, and the distance along this circle between two max-speed points is equal to `θ*maxSpeed`, where θ is the angle between those velocities. If you can accelerate by `maxAcceleration` and your step is `dt` seconds long, that gives you a distance along the circle of `maxAcceleration*dt`, or an angle of `maxAcceleration*dt/maxSpeed`. So if your current velocity angle is θ, at the end of the step the angle should be `θ +/- maxAcceleration*dt/maxSpeed`.